# Is there any restriction for v-model in vue?

Tags: vuejs3

I am getting syntax error for the following code snippet.

```
   <Dropdown v-model="function.moduleId" :options="modules" optionValue="moduleId" 
     :filter="true" optionLabel="moduleName" required="true">
    </Dropdown>
```

Problem is with `v-model="function.moduleId"` this. It seems to me I can't use 'function' word for v-model name. But for a good naming convention I have to use this. Any idea?

Comment: I dont know what naming convention supports using language keywords for variable names, but Im surprised you could even use that word for a variable name, my vue simply assumes its a function if I use that, normal js/nodejs also dont even allow me to use function as a variable name. if you really care about the meaning you could use a synonym for function

Comment: Thanks for this nice clarification. I used functionModel and now it works fine. Yes, such keyword should be avoid in an js/nodejs too.